# Do TWA's have access to IndexedDB?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, progressive-web-apps, twa

I have read conflicting answers on this. On the google site it says that TWAs do not have access to things like local browser storage. However i have read elsewhere that the TWA portion of the app doesnt the the PWA inside of it does have access.

Could anyone clear this up for me?

The app relies on local storage so im wondering if i need to migrate to react native

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the application running inside a Trusted Web Activity have access to IndexedDB.

The confusion here is probably caused by the fact that an application that uses Trusted Web Activity will have an Android part and a PWA part. The Android part, which is implemented using Java or Kotlin, will not have access to IndexedDB, but the web part has access to all browser APIs.